# switch to currency in magento 2 programmatically

Tags: magento2, currency

I'm trying to switch to "euro" in magento2 **index.php** for some visitors, but i didn't find how to set currency, this is my code :

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$storeManager = $objectManager->create("\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface");
$currencyManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\Currency');
```

Comment: Did you manage to achieve this?

Comment: You can take reference from here : https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-switch-currency-programmatically-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

public function __construct(

```
     \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager

){

     $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;

}




 $currency = isset($post->currency)?$post->currency:'INR';

                    $storeManager = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class);
                    if ($currency) {
                       $storeManager->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currency);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a module on my local store that adds a predispatch event. It requires the currency settings on your store to get correctly configured:

- you need the currency you want to be auto-selected to be within the allowed currencies of your system
- you also need to have your currency rates to be defined (Stores / Currency Rates)

At this point, without adding the changes below, you should see a currency switcher in your store (this is if your theme is Luma anyway)

Then, you may add the below event in your system. The currency is hard-coded to EUR in my code but you can change this using geoip (I guess this part was something you know)

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
            <observer name="currency_initialisation_predispatch" instance="Mbs\CurrencySwitcher\Observer\PreDispatchObserver" shared="false" />
        </event>
    </config>
```

and the observer code as per below

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\CurrencySwitcher\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class PreDispatchObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        // this can be coming from geoip PHP function
        // php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php
        $currency = 'EUR';

        if ($this->getStoreCurrency() !== $currency) {
            $this->storeManager->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currency);
        }
    }

    private function getStoreCurrency()
    {
        return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    }
}
```